# Make all values of an array negative or change sign

Tags: arrays, swift

In SWIFT, is there a quick and efficient way to make all values of an array change sign (positive values become negative and vice-versa) ?

For example:

```
let x: [Double] =  [1.0, 2.0, -3.0, 4.0, -5.0]
```

Should become:

```
// x = [-1.0, -2.0, 3.0, -4.0, 5.0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a fast solution for large arrays then you can use 
[`cblas_dscal()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/1513084-cblas_dscal) ("scalar multiplication, double precision") from the Accelerate framework:

```
import Accelerate 

var x = [1.0, 2.0, -3.0, 4.0, -5.0]
cblas_dscal(Int32(x.count), -1.0, &x, 1)

print(x) // [-1.0, -2.0, 3.0, -4.0, 5.0]
```

*Remark:* There is also `cblas_sscal()` for `Float` arrays ("single precision").

**Performance comparison:** Here is a quite simple performance comparison
of the various methods:

```
let N = 1_000_000 // # of array elements
let R = 100 // # of repetitions

func test1() {
    var x = (0..<N).map { _ in drand48() }
    let start = Date()
    for _ in 0..<R {
        for i in x.indices { x[i] = -x[i] }
    }
    let time = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
    print("x[i] = -x[i]     ", time)
}

func test2() {
    var x = (0..<N).map { _ in drand48() }
    let start = Date()
    for _ in 0..<R {
        for i in x.indices { x[i].negate() }
    }
    let time = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
    print("x[i].negate()    ", time)
}

func test3() {
    var x = (0..<N).map { _ in drand48() }
    let start = Date()
    for _ in 0..<R {
        x = x.map { -$0 }
    }
    let time = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
    print("x.map { -$0 }    ", time)
}

func test4() {
    var x = (0..<N).map { _ in drand48() }
    let start = Date()
    for _ in 0..<R {
        cblas_dscal(Int32(x.count), -1.0, &x, 1)
    }
    let time = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
    print("cblas_dscal      ", time)
}

test1()
test2()
test3()
test4()
```

*Results* (on a 3.5 GHz Intel iMac, compiled and run in Release configuration:)

```
x[i] = -x[i]      0.0492849946022034
x[i].negate()     0.0635690093040466
x.map { -$0 }     0.285757005214691
cblas_dscal       0.0506410002708435
```

As it turns out, `cblas_dscal()` has about the same speed as
an explicit loop with `x[i] = -x[i]` or `x[i].negate()`, but is
significantly faster than the `map()` method.

Of course the results may be different on a different hardware, or with
other array sizes.

As usual, start with the method which you are most familiar with and
look for faster methods if it turns out to be performance-critical.

Comment: Thanks all. @ Martin: I need double precision as some arrays are filter coefficients with lots of decimal places.

Comment: @Pat: `x` *is* a `Double` array. The final remark was just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Ok thanks Martin! Just noticed that you used the double precision function.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe you ever have to explicitly `import Swift`. Also the last argument of `cblas_dscal` can just be a literal `1` and `multiplier` can be a `let` :).

Comment: @Hamish: Thanks, fixed. There are other functions in the Accelerate framework which require variables for *all* arguments ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41661278/1187415)), so I did not check here. – I added "import Swift" only to emphasize that "import Foundation" is not needed, but that might have been misleading.

Comment: @Pat: The Accelerate framework might have more useful routines for your purpose: matrix multiplication, linear equation system solving, fast fourier transform, ...

Comment: Thanks Martin! I am also looking to add contents of two equal count arrays "element-by-element." So, let a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] and let b = [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]. I want a c = [5.0, 7.0, 9.0]

Comment: @MartinR if you have the time, could you include the `negate()` approach as well in your benchmarking? The `-` prefix will eventually call `negate()` on a copy of `self` (for each element) and return the copy which is then used in the value replacement (assignment); as compared to `negate()`:s direct in-place mutation. (I suspect, however, that a release build will possible optimize the former operation to the latter, so that there will be no performance difference between them).

Comment: @dfri: Benchmarks added. I have no idea why `negate()` is (marginally) slower than `x[i] = -x[i]`, but I get similar results on multiple runs.

Comment: @MartinR thanks! I see the same behaviour as you; maybe some mini-overhead using mutating methods. Also, the non-mutating `x[i] = x[i].negated()` seems extremely slightly marginally faster than `x[i] = -x[i]` (but blas being marginally faster than them all).

Answer (score 2):

How about map:

```
let x: [Double] =  [1.0, 2.0, -3.0, 4.0, -5.0]

let invertedX = x.map({$0 * (-1)})
```

result:

> [-1.0, -2.0, 3.0, -4.0, 5.0]

Comment: Why `as Double`? Just say `x.map{-$0}`

Comment: Sure thing, first version didn't had specified type (let x : [Double]) so I had to specify it do have wanted result

Comment: The type of a floating point literal is inferred by default to be `Double`, you don't have to specify it. Even if it was some other type, you cannot just convert numeric types with `as`.

Comment: I always thought it was Float... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### The `negate()` method of `FloatingPoint`

If you choose to proceed with a non-Accelerate approach, then you might prefer (e.g. semantics) using [the `negate()` method of `FloatingPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1849560-negate) to negate the values of the array in-place.

```
var x =  [1.0, 2.0, -3.0, 4.0, -5.0]
for i in x.indices { x[i].negate() }

print(x) // [-1.0, -2.0, 3.0, -4.0, 5.0]
```

In fact, [the `-` prefix operator from `FloatingPoint`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPoint.swift.gyb#L1481) simply calls [the `negated()` method of `FloatingPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1848123-negated), where the implementation of the latter simply [makes use of the `negate()` method](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPoint.swift.gyb#L1867) to copy, negate and return and negated copy of `self`.

> ```
> extension FloatingPoint {
>
>     // ...
>
>     public func negated() -> Self {
>       var rhs = self
>       rhs.negate()
>       return rhs
>     }
> }
>
> // ...
>
> public prefix func - <T : FloatingPoint>(x: T) -> T {
>   return x.negated()
> }
> ```

Finally, the `negate()` method itself is implemented in the conformance of `Double` (/`Float`, `Float80`, `CGFloat`) to [`BinaryFloatingPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/binaryfloatingpoint), calling the `Builtint` function `fneg_FPIEEE` on `self` ([source here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb)

> ```
> % for self_type in all_floating_point_types(): 
> %{ 
> Self = self_type.stdlib_name
>
>   // ...
>
>   extension ${Self}: BinaryFloatingPoint {
>
>     // ...
>     public mutating func negate() {
>       _value = Builtin.fneg_FPIEEE${bits}(self._value)
>     }   
>   }
>
>   // ... 
> }
> ```

I haven't found a reference for the implemention of the `Builtin.fneg_FPIEEE` method (Floating Point IEEE), but most likely it simply flips the sign bit of `self`.

Comment: @SteveKuo how so? The mutation should be comparable to the element replacement in the `for` loop of the accepted answer (which also describes that the `map` solution is slower). Possible the loop above shouldn't refer to `array.indices` though, as I'm unsure how it affects the `isUniquelyReferenced` state of the array `x` within the loop. Will wait for the benchmarls from MartinR (see comments under the accepted answer).