# Compiler error on nil using vDSP_normalizeD in an SPM project

Tags: swift, macos, swift-package-manager

How to a pass a nil pointer to a C API in Swift?

More specifically, I'm trying the following:

```
import Accelerate

let v = [1.0, 2.0]
var m = 0.0
var sd = 0.0
// 3rd arg is of type: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>?
vDSP_normalizeD(v, 1, nil, 0, &m, &sd, vDSP_Length(v.count))
```

Documentation for `vDSP_normalizeD` is found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450154-vdsp_normalized).

This method of passing nil seems valid for earlier versions of Swift as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133107/swift-accelerate-for-mean-standard-deviation/42133548#42133548). However using Xcode v10.1 / Swift v4.2.1 it gives the following error message:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'

The following solution does not work either:

```
let p: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>? = nil
vDSP_normalizeD(v, 1, p, 0, &m, &sd, vDSP_Length(v.count))
```

giving the following error message:

> Value of optional type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'

In earlier versions of Swift the following was possible:

```
let p = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>(nil)
```

but it now generates the following error:

> Ambiguous use of 'init'

So, my question is - how do I pass a nil pointer to a C API using a modern version of Swift?

Comment: Maybe `UnsafeMutablePointer(bitPattern: 0)`?

Comment: As far as I tested, your first code compiles without problems, in both iOS SDK and macOS SDK. Are you doing something special to your project?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!

Thanks [OOPer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6541007/ooper) for verifying that it does in fact compile and asking: *Are you doing something special to your project?*.

I'm maintaining my project through [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/) and apparently, when generating the Xcode project, it defaults to MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.10. However, creating a new project directly via Xcode v10.1 the default is MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.12.

The above code requires 10.11 and I did not understand that SPM didn't use a later deployment target. This is all solved now by using a Package.xcconfig file with the variable: `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11`.

The documentation didn't help from start either. The help for [vDSP_normalizeD](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450154-vdsp_normalized) doesn't mention anything about target requirements, instead that information is found in the documentation for its float cousin [vDSP_normalize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450106-vdsp_normalize).

Btw, this might be obvious for some, but it took me some hours to figure it out. Thanks again [OOPer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6541007/ooper) for pointing me somewhat in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard because I could not test it, but I think is because the initializer:

try this:

```
let p: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>? = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.init(mutating: nil)
```

And let me know if it works for you